# Llenar datagridview con condicion c# Sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Buenas amigos.
Estoy creando un proyecto y me acabo de topar con algo que no logro resolver.
Tengo un datagridview donde muestro toda la información de un empleado:

```
        private void Mostrar(){ var query = from p in db.Usuarios_ 
                  select p;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (var items in query)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                                         items.Usuario.ToString(),
                                         items.Numidentidad.ToString(),
                                         items.NombreCom.ToString(),
                                         items.Genero.ToString(),
                                         items.Correo.ToString(),
                                         items.Telefono.ToString(),
                                         items.Cargo.ToString()
                );
        }
     }
```

Ahora, mi dolor de cabeza vino al tratar de llenar otro datagridview solo si en el registro Cargo se cumplía la condicion que Cargo tenia que ser igual a "Maestro" o sea que solo me llenara el datagridview con todo los registro del maestro.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agrega la condición a la consulta linq **where p.Cargo == "Maestro"** como se muestra

```
            var query = from p in db.Usuarios_
                        where p.Cargo == "Maestro"
                        select p;
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (var items in query)
            {

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                                             items.Usuario.ToString(),
                                             items.Numidentidad.ToString(),
                                             items.NombreCom.ToString(),
                                             items.Genero.ToString(),
                                             items.Correo.ToString(),
                                             items.Telefono.ToString(),
                                             items.Cargo.ToString()
                    );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo podes hacer mejor con una expresión lambda, es decir:

```
var query = db.Usuarios_.Where(x=>x.cargo == "Maestro").ToList();
```

y te recomiendo, para quitarte ese foreach, en el datagridview, crear tus columnas y por cada columna, donde dice DataPropertyName, colocar el nombre del campo, en el caso del numero de identidad, numIdentidad, etc.

luego colocas dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns=false;
y por ultimo:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
```

eso último como sugerencia para ahorrar lineas de codigo, Espero te sirva!